# Variable repeating the same value when form closed

Tags: c#

I have declared a variable called paymentId. When I open a windows form this paymentId is initialized to a certain value and I can add payments (Butter, bread..etc),save to the database and close the form. After closing the form I want to open the form so that I can add another payment (Milk etc..) but the paymentId is not changing and the same paymentId is saved in the database.

```
public partial class PaymentAutoPayment : Form
{
    int firstRun = 0;
    double total = 0;
    public static Random rnd = new Random();
    String cashierId = "";
    public static int randomString = rnd.Next(9999, 99999)
    string paymentId = "RecId-" + randomString.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

public static int randomString is static. It is initialized exactly once, ever.

```
public static int randomString = rnd.Next(9999, 99999);
```

No matter now many times you convert the same int value to a string, it'll still be the same int.

```
string paymentId = "RecId-" + randomString.ToString();
```

Try this:

```
string paymentId = "RecId-" + rnd.Next(9999, 99999).ToString();
```

Comment: If i take that off i get the error. "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static int randomString = rnd.Next(9999, 99999)
```

This is declared as `static` and only executed once during the whole program runtime, and never changes. Use instead:

```
string paymentId = "RecId-" + rnd.Next(9999, 99999).ToString();
```

Comment: If I remove static from the declaration i get the error. "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" I tried that before posting.

Comment: @Elias nowhere i am saying you should remove static?